# How can I create a fulfillment for intent in Google Actions?

Tags: actions-on-google

I created a Google Action using the Google Actions console, then pulled it using the gactions CLI and now I am trying to connect my intents to a fulfillment webhook but don't know how.

I tried using the following code for the fulfillment from the Google Action help:

```
const { conversation } = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require{'firebase-functions'};

const app = conversation();

app.handle('sayHello', conv =&gt; {
  conv.add("Hi there! It\'s good to see you!");
  })

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Conversation doesn't seem to exist and I am having trouble finding other ways of accepting requests.

This is my current directory:

[image: current directory]

How can I send requests to the fulfillment webhook from intents?

Comment: Are you using Dialogflow? If so have you checked the Fulfillment tab and made sure you have entered the URL to your Firebase Cloud Function?

Answer (score 0):

The `conversation` is the term for the container when using Actions Builder or Actions SDK along with the `@assistant/conversation` library.

If you are using either one, you should change libraries.

If you are using Dialogflow, you would want to keep `actions-on-google` as the library and switch the method from `app.handle` to `app.intent`.

Additionally, this may be an encoding problem, but when your handler contains `conv =&gt; {` there should be a 'greater than' symbol instead:

`conv => {`

Comment: we are not using Dialogflow, we are trying to get all user input to our server so we can process it there. from what we saw there exists something like actions.intent.text, but we are slightly confused about when the webhook gets called from the intent (or scenes)

Comment: So you are using Actions SDK in a similar way to [custom NLU](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-custom-nlu-nodejs/)?